# cache-control not working without etag

Tags: http, http-headers, cache-control

I am sending the following header in the reponse. `"Cache-Control: public, max-age=300"`, but still every time I hit refresh I get a `200` response(the request is made to he server again). Same happens if I add the "Expires" header.

But if I add a ETag to the headers, then I get `304` on refresh(the request goes to the server, the server prepares the response, then matches the ETag and returns a `204` response).

What should I change so that `"Cache-Control"` header is used and the 
content is served from local cache and no request is sent to the server until the age becomes more than `"max-age"`?

EDIT: Here is an image that doesn't get cached https://image-dev-dot-quizizz-dev.appspot.com/resource/gs/quizizz-image/rejected.jpeg

Comment: are you sure `max-age=300`? it sets for 300 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Your image **is** in proxy cache - notice that in a response you get `Age` header. Furthermore, every next request in 300 seconds takes much less time. Why is the status not 304? According to [this article](http://www.benhallbenhall.com/2012/03/http-codes-200-from-cache-304/):

> 200 (from cache) vs 304
>
> Now the other day while performing a site performance audit I noticed
>   that a lot of our assets were returning 304 statuses.  While comparing
>   another site I noticed that it was returning a 200 (from cache) status
>   code.  This intrigued me and I wanted to dig deeper.
>
> It turns out that when a 200 (from cache) response is given it means
>   that a future expiration date on the content is set.  **In essence the
>   browser doesn’t even really communicate with the server to check on
>   the file.  It knows not to do it until the expiration date has
>   expired.**
>
> By contrast a 304 goes to the server and receives a response back that
>   the data has not change.  **The server is telling the browser to use the
>   cache as a result.**

Comment: If this is the case, then why does adding `Etag` start giving `304`. It should still give `200(from cache)` for 300 secs and after that should give `304`?

Comment: It seems if you add Etag, browser always checks it.